# How to write an expression two calculate sum of values if gender is equal to Male and Female in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have got the sql query where I have three values inside Gender column - Male, Female, Other, another column with school name, and no of student.
So after running this query result looks like this ---

| SchoolName | Gender | NoOfStudents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | Male | 12 |
| xyz | Female | 13 |
| xyz | Other | 1 |
| abc | Male | 22 |
| abc | Female | 10 |
| abc | Other | 2 |

I am displaying this query in SSRS report with the help of matrix so my report looks like this

| SchoolName | Female | Male | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 13 | 12 | 1 |
| abc | 10 | 22 | 2 |

Now in my report I want another column added next to the "Other column" which will be "Total for M and F" which will show value which is sum of Male and Female

| SchoolName | Female | Male | Other | TotalForM&F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 13 | 12 | 1 | 25 (Male + Female) |
| abc | 10 | 22 | 2 | 32 (Male + Female) |

I want to know what expression I should write to get the above result for column TotalForM&F?

I have tried writing something like this =IIf(Fields!Gender.Value Like "Male", Fields!NoOfStudent.Value, 0) + IIf(Fields!Gender.Value Like "Female", Fields!NoOfStudent.Value, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first determine if the row needs to be included and then sum the values within the scope of the textbox so something like this should work

```
=SUM(
    IIF(
        Fields!Gender.Value = "Male" OR Fields!Gender.Value = "Female",
        Fields!NoOfStudent.Value,
        0
        )
    )
```